# Why do i need to use javac to compile my code?

Tags: java

Let's say i have a code like this :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int x = 5;
        // Widening Casting
        double myNum = x;
        System.out.println(x + " " + myNum);
    }
}
```

Now i write the following commands in powershell changing the value of x from 5 to 6 once in my code and saving it, it works perfectly fine. But tutorials online suggest me to use javac for compilation. Why so?

[image]

Comment: It's a feature of Java 11+: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330

Comment: @Andy Turner the article was really helpful thnx :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Java 11 onwards, the `java` command is able to compile and run a single Java source file with a `static void main(String[])` entry point method.  (This feature was added as [JEP 330](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330).)

The online tutorials are correct for Java 10 and earlier, and they are correct for cases where more than one Java source file needs to be compiled.